# How show all images kept in a folder using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am not that much familiar with JavaScript. So please help me if there is an easy way.
I am making a LAN Webpage which will show all the pictures stored in a folder. But adding all those thousand of images one by one using div and img tag is very hard. So I thought if there is an way to automatically add images from the folder to my html. I think a for loop using the same image name with just different index numbers *(I will rename the images - like img (1), img (2))* will be useful for this but I don't know how to do this?

Here is my html code (Using Materialize Framework) -

```
<body>
<div class="fixed-navbar">   <--I have to write this every time I want to add image. So this is where I am wanting some automation-->
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper white">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo black-text">LAN Page</a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="videos.html" class="black-text">Videos</a></li>
                <li class="active blue lighten-3"><a href="#" class=" black-text">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: is it a nodejs based server or just a static html page?

Comment: Are you enabled to use server side code? Like PHP or Node.js?

Comment: No it is not a server side code. It is just a static HTML page as I will only use it in my LAN  Network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to dynamically add HTML to your HTML page. Let me show you how.

```js
import * as img from 'images/path_to_img.ext';
for (var i=0;i<img.length;i++)
{
document.querySelector("image-container").innerHTML+=('<img src='+img[i].src);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot I think it will work the way I am wanting. But I cant understand this part - 'images/path_to_img.ext';. Do I need to include a file or just the folder path here ?

Comment: I added this code but it doesn't seem to work.

`<div class="image-container">
    </div>

    <script>
        import * as img from 'images\folder';
for (var i=0;i<img.length;i++)
{
document.querySelector("image-container").innerHTML+=('<img src='+img[i].src);
}
    </script>`

I am just wanting to add the images from the images folder automatically.

Answer (score 0):

No server side might require you to let JS know how many picture files there are.

```
let max = 10; // Replace with Number of Images
let body = document.body;
for (let x = 0; x < max; x++) {
  body.innerHTML += ` // Template Literals. MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
   <div class="fixed-navbar">   
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper white">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo black-text">LAN Page</a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="videos.html" class="black-text">Videos</a></li>
                <li class="active blue lighten-3"><a href="#" class=" black-text">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div> 
  `
}
```

It does seem weird to me that you want to just add the "LAN Page" thing and not the image itself. If you need the image. Comment It.

Comment: No I am wanting to add the image brother.